# Hide certain div/ class only at front page

Tags: css

Good day everyone, there is a question from me here, how can i hide certain div or class at my front page but to show it (div/class) at the other pages..

the div/ class i mentioned is connected from each others( front page and the other pages),
if i use

```
#page-element {
    display: none;
}
```

it mights end up ,all that elements gone.....

Comment: Please make sure you are posting on the right site.

Comment: Take a look at the classes generated by `body_class()` for certain requests.

Answer (score 3):

If the WordPress theme is doing it's job correctly, then it's using the [`body_class()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/body_class/) function to output the classes on the `<body>` tag. If that's the case, then on the home page, it will add the `.home` class, and we can target that class as follows:

```
.home #page-element { display: none; }
```

If the theme isn't using the `body_class()` function on the `<body>` tag, then this won't work.

Comment: Nathan, please … you know how it works: An answer should provide at least an explanation. And if the comment that is needed to explain why this does not work out as answer, then your answer should probably just have been a comment :)

Comment: Oops. I thought I was commenting, not posting an answer. I'll add a bit